# Why do some words become amalgamated?

Tags: orthography

Why  do some words in English become joined together and what is the criteria that prevents common phrases of doing the same?

For example:

> None the less > Nonetheless
>
> Never the less > Nevertheless
>
> Some what > Somewhat

Answer (score 1):

Actually in English there are quite a few words that are made up by other words joined together: moreover, someone, notwithstanding, whereas etc. one possible reason may be the fact that **many English words are derived from old Germanic-based languages**, and in those languages it was common to combine words to create compound words.
For example, an equivalent German word for *nonetheless* is "trotzdem". It's made up of two words, "trotz" and "dem", or "despite" and "that", a parallel construction to the English.

Actually *[nonetheless](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonetheless,&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,nonetheless;,c0)* appear as a single word since the 20's but other compound [words](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moreover,%20notwithstanding,%20whereas%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,moreover;,c0;.t1;,notwithstanding;,c0;.t1;,whereas;,c0)  have been used as a single entity  much before that date. 
 I think that also  the continuous usage  of words often used together have  resulted in the creation of single words.